# Quantifying the bias of a quantile estimator based on order statistics, and its relation to asymptotic unbiasedness

Tags: quantiles, unbiased-estimator, order-statistics

From what I understand, the quantile estimator based on order statistics is asymptotically unbiased (and follows a Normal distribution).

I have been looking for a quantification of the non-asymptotic bias and found out that Okolewski and Rychlik (2001) obtained a sharp distribution-free bound. For the $p$-th quantile, $\xi_p$:
$$\frac{E(X_{(r)}) - \xi_p}{\sigma} \leq \frac{1- I_p(r, n-r + 1)}{[p(1-p)]^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$
where $I_p$ is the incomplete Beta function, $n$ is the number of samples drawn from the distribution of $X$ and $r = np$.

I noticed that the RHS of the inequality is increasing in $n$, i.e., by increasing the number of samples $n$, the RHS of the inequality gets larger. This is somewhat counter-intuitive since the estimator is asymptotically unbiased.

My questions are:

1. Given that the estimator is asymptotically unbiased, why does the bound increase as $n$ increases? I understand that having a larger upper bound is not contradictory to having asymptotic unbiasedness, but I would like to know if there is an intuitive explanation for why the bound has this property.
2. Is there an alternative bound on the bias that can be used directly to infer the asymptotic unbiasedness property of the estimator?